# SSL Certificate error when create GitHub repo with Ansible Module

Tags: github, ssl, ansible, ssl-certificate, repo

I'm using the github_repo ansible module to accessing our entreprise github repository.

As test I've created a personal access token to access it. Unfortunately I received an **SSLError** despite that `http.sslverify: false` is configured in git.
Here's the error:

```
"msg": "Unexpected error. SSLError(MaxRetryError(\"HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /user (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),))\",),)"
```

As anyone an idea how to resolve this? does anyone experience with ansible and github?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `git`; you're using the GitHub REST API. Your `git` configuration settings are not relevant.

You need to install your enterprise CA certificate somewhere that the Python [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) can find it (this module is ultimately used by the `github_repo` module to make http requests).

It looks like the simplest method is to put the CA certificate in a file and then set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to point to the location of this file.

There doesn't appear to be a way to disable SSL verification via an environment variable (there is some discussion on this topic in issue [#6071](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6071)).

Comment: I'll go in this direction and thank you for your answer